# Javascript Nested Object - creating a function accessing nested object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Need some help with coding question below. I've been stuck and would appreciate some help here!

--------------------------Question Nested Object---------------------------

> *Write a function pumpkinPicker that, given a deeply nested object, returns the count of the number of 'pumpkin' strings stored as a value
>   in any of the nested objects.*

```
var pumpkinPatch = {
  meadow: {
    byTheRock: 'apples',
    byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'
  },
  hill: {
    byTheBench: {
      leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',
      rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'
      },
      topOfHill: 'apples'
      }
    };


pumpkinPicker(pumpkinPatch); //*answer should prompt => 3*
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but this might help to set you in the right direction:

```js
function countValuesFromObject(object, value) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in object) {
        var val = object[prop];
        if (val === value) {
            count++;
        }
        if (typeof val === 'object') {
            count += countValuesFromObject(val, value);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively and using a `for ... in` loop as follows:

```js
const pumpkinPicker = patch => {
  total = 0;
  
  for (const k in patch) {
    if (typeof patch[k] === "object") {
      total += pumpkinPicker(patch[k]);
    }
    else if (patch[k] === "pumpkin") {
      total++;
    }
  }
  
  return total;
};

var pumpkinPatch = {
  meadow: {
    byTheRock: 'apples',
    byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'
  },
  hill: {
    byTheBench: {
      leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',
      rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'
    },
    topOfHill: 'apples'
  }
};


console.log(pumpkinPicker(pumpkinPatch));
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` inside a recursive function makes this pretty concise:

```js
var pumpkinPatch = {meadow: {byTheRock: 'apples',byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'},hill: {byTheBench: {leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'},topOfHill: 'apples'},};
  
const pumpkinPicker = (obj) =>
    typeof obj === 'object'
        ? Object.values(obj).reduce((count, value) => count + pumpkinPicker(value), 0 )
        : obj === "pumpkin" ? 1 : 0


let count =   pumpkinPicker(pumpkinPatch); //*answer should prompt => 3*
console.log(count)
```